# Should I have static init() called before any instance is created

Tags: c#, java, oop, design-patterns

I have a class which initializes connection to one of the servers that we are dealing with, then subscribes to various events on server and then performs various transactions on the same server once it receives subscribed notifications.

I made connection object `static` so that there will always be single connection to server open across all instances. The problem is that those transaction on server need to be done only when notification is received. And since there are different types of notifications I am subscribed, I cant tell which thread will create instance of the class first and perform transaction.

In nutshell I cant tell when and where the class instance will be created. But for all those instances I want same connection used. So I want that connection to be initialized before any instance of class is created. So I created `static init(params)` and initialized that connection by calling `Class.init(params)`. And everytime the notification occurs I simply call default constructor to perform the transaction on it.

**However somehow first calling `init()` method on class and then somewhere after sometime calling default constructor to get instance is what I am doing first time and hence dont know if it is right approach.**

Comment: C# but I think it wont make any difference

Comment: Well each language has its own syntax and rules so what applies to such less common cases may vary.

Comment: I would see an example code but it looks like some kind of lazy (object creation is deferred until last moment). It doesn't smell bad, what's your concerns about that?

Comment: IMO wrong thing is just to mix this static init() method in a non static class. I would make its constructor private and add a static method GetInstance (or something like that) to make this _contract_ more clear. I would even consider to have GetInstance() and GetInstance(parameters) instead.

Comment: Bold-faced in my question what exactly I am finding awkward: it requires calling `Class.init()` at the beginning of my app and then I dont know when and where I will do `Class obj = Class();` and then inside `obj.method()` I will use variable initialized by `Class.init()`. If I look at framework classes they usually call `init()` on instance.

Comment: I would make everything static (like a true singleton or factory) (see previous comment). At least it's clear it's not a normal "instance" of object (obtained from a normal constructor).

Comment: @Adriano but then `getInstance()` will reinitialize static member everytime or at least a check for `null` has to be added to it which may prove unnecessary once initializaion is done.

Comment: Yes but it's less expansive a null-check than an object creation (and btw...you're dealing with a network connection so this time is always negligible). Assuming performance are not an issue here the point IMO is to make clear to readers that you're not just creating a "normal" object (who would expect that an object instance parameters come from a static method call done before?)

Comment: Ohkay I think really confused with whether I singleton or not: I believe I should make class singleton only when there is such constraint put on externally. Here it will be no problem to have multiple instances. But if it causes problem to have multiple instances of this class run some methods concurrently (if those transactions run concurrently in multiple threads through different instances), then I would have thought to make singleton. - am I wrong?

Comment: Who will see a factory method (or a singleton pattern) will understand there is also something else (and...he'll be less astonished to see an initialization method).

Comment: Singleton and concurrency are unrelated (as concepts). Singleton: only one instance. Concurrency: one or more instances will access to same resource concurrently. Singleton object will have to manage concurrency for both its own state (private fields) and shared resources. Non singleton will have to manage concurrency with shared resources only.

Comment: I was thinking what should I do that adhere to OOP. Should I go for Singleton when it can work without singleton. Or late may rephrase it - what should be parameters to decide if I need single instance all time - I thought concurrency is one such. @Adriano

Comment: If this seems confusing you may split your class in two: a singleton instance (that represents shared network connection), singleton and initialized with init() and a "standard" object (multiple instances) that will synchronize access to shared resource.

Comment: **Singleton or not doesn't make you "more OOP".** Do what's best for your scenario (in terms of readibility, performance and maintainability)

Comment: Right that may satisfy me, will think more on it or else will raise new question :p

Answer (score 0):

In java you can use a static{} statement (not a method, but a static block of code executed before the class instanciation)... in C# I don't know how you can do it.

But... why you don't use the singleton pattern for your connection?

Comment: there is static constructor in C#, but anyways I cant pass parameters to both

Comment: Because there can be multiple instances of this class. I believe I should make class singleton only when there is such constraint put on externally. Here it will be no problem to have multiple instances. But if it causes problem to have multiple instances of this class run some methods concurrently, then I would have thought to make singleton.

Comment: Ohkay so if I need to have some variable to be shared across instances, should I always go for singleton? I think it calls for `static` member. Am I going wrong?

Comment: What roman said.  The connection is distinct from the things that use it.  Make it its own (Singleton) class.  Singleton over static as you can swap singleton implementations in and out when needed but not static methods.

Comment: Yes, they wrote exactly what I said: use singleton (just) for your connection. An idea can be to wrap it inside your class (and provide it with setter/getters for your shared properties).